# De-recursifyng a recursive sequence

Tags: recursion

I'm working on a recursive function for my IB Maths exploration, of the form $f(x)=f((x+a)^{-b})$
I've worked out a general formula for the n-th term of the sequence when $b = 1$, but whenever I'm trying to apply my knowledge to $b = 2$ or higher I end up with a ton of algebra and I'm not able to derive a general formula, is there any way that I can use to express the sequence? (terms ahead)
$$ y = x + a $$

$$U_1=1/y^b $$
$$U_2 = {y^{b^2}\over(ay^b+1)^b} $$
$$U_3={(ay^b+1)^{b^2}\over(y^{b^2}+(ay^b+1)^b)^b} $$
$$U_4={(y^{b^2}+(ay^b+1)^b)^{b^2}\over((ay^b+1)^{b^2}+(y^{b^2}+(ay^b+1)^b)^b)^b} $$

I'm sorry for the poor formatting of the sequence but I'm still getting started with this system.

Comment: What is $U_{n}$ in terms of $U_{n-1}$?

Comment: $U_n = (U_n-1 + a) {^-b} $

Comment: $U_n=(U_{n-1}+a)^{-b}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, sorry I'm still trying to get used to the formula system

Comment: I don't see any way to get close to a solution. If a closed form exists, it will probably be in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much anyway for your expertise!